# Changing logger chunk size in a rails (production env)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, logging

Rails logger in production writes to production.log in big and slow chunks.

How can I eliminate this chuck writing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Rails logger does buffering in production to not overwhelm the io subsystem with logs. It should still flush the log after each request (or after 1000 lines, whatever comes first)

You can control this buffer by setting the `auto_flushing` setting in an initializer:

```
Rails.logger.auto_flushing = 10
```

This will set the logger to flush after 10 log lines. While you can set that to `1`, it is probably not an overly great idea to do so in production.

Comment: This code is deprecated, found this: ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger#auto_flushing is deprecated. Either set the sync level on the underlying file handle like this. Or tune your filesystem. The FS cache is now what controls flushing.

Comment: I still don't know what to do

Comment: Well, then tune your filesystem. Newer versions of Rails (probably > 3.2) just issue a `write` call which gets eventually written to the underlying filesystem. When that happens is up to the kernel/filesystem.